# error: no matching function for call to 'Faculty::Faculty()' in c++

Tags: c++, function, class, inheritance, virtual-functions

I am getting this [`ERROR`][1] on running the below code. I am a new bee in c++ world who got this error if someone could just help me to solve this kind of error that will be great. Thanks in Advance :).

- Here's the error-> [image: 1]!

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class Employee{
    public:
    string name;
    string organisation;
    string qualification;
    int salary;
    Employee(){
        cout<<"Enter Employee name: ";
        cin>>name;
        cout<<"Enter organisation: ";
        cin>>organisation;
        cout<<"Enter qualification: ";
        cin>>qualification;
    }
    void disp(){
        cout<<"The Name of the employee is: "<<name<<endl;
        cout<<"The Employee's organisation: "<<organisation<<endl;
        cout<<"The Qualification of the employee is: "<<qualification<<endl;
    }
    virtual void print(){
        cout<<"Inside Emplyee!";
    }
};
class Faculty:public Employee{
    public:
    string course;
    int workload;
    Faculty(string course, int workload){
        cout<<"Enter course: ";
        cin>>course;
        cout<<"Enter Workload: ";
        cin>> workload;
    
    }
    void print(){
        cout<<"Course: "<<course<<endl;
        cout<<"Workload: "<<workload<<endl;
    }
};
class Staff: public Employee{
    public:
    string designation;
    string job_description;
    Staff(string designation, string job_description){
        cout<<"Enter designation: ";
        cin>>designation;
        cout<<"Enter job_description: ";
        cin>>job_description;
    }
    void print(){
        cout<<"Designation: "<<designation<<endl;
        cout<<"Job Description: "<<job_description<<endl;
    }
};
int main(){
    //This program is written by kajal
    Employee e;
    e.disp();
    Faculty f;
    f.print();
    return 0;
}
```

Here's it's actual Question,
Define a class Employee with data members – Name, Organization, Qualification and Salary. In this class define member functions as given below:

- parameterless constructor to initialize the data members - Name,
  Organization, Qualification and Salary.
- A function disp() for displaying the Name, Organization, Qualification and Salary. • A pure
  virtual function void print().
- Derive the class Faculty from the Employee class using public inheritance. In the Faculty class declare data members: Course and Workload(number of working hours of a faculty in
  a week) of the appropriate data type and define a parametric constructor for initializing these data members. Override the print() function in Faculty class to display the Course and
  Workload .
- Derive a class Staff from the Employee class using public inheritance. This derived class declares data members -Designation and Job_Description of the appropriate data type.
- Define the parametric constructor of this class to initialize the values of Designation and Job_Description. Override the print function in this class to display Designation and Job_Description .
- Define the main() function and declare one object each of Faculty class and Staff class.
  Use run time polymorphism and display the details of Faculty and Staff class objects.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557

Comment: By defining some constructor with parameters you have disabled default constructor, but you are trying to use it.

Comment: You should not read any input in the constructors. The arguments should be read elsewhere and passed to the constructors.

Comment: Is it easier to do a screen snapshot or highlight all the text and copy to the clipboard?  Text can be easily resized, not so for images.